# Cannot Install Updates Windows 8.1 Error 80070490

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-update, updates

When I attempt to install updates I recieve the error code 80070490. 
I ran the command SFC /SCANNOW, which returned "Found corrupt files, but was unable to fix some of them.."
I also ran Dism /Online /cleanup-image /restorehealth, however that stopped at 40% and returned an error.
I would appreciate help with this situation, thanks.

Comment: If you want help, you have to do better then, "it gave an error" because that tells us nothing except "its not working".

Comment: Sounds like you had/have disk corruption and it has effected OS files and your WinSXS repository. You need to identify the corrupted files and replace them with known-good versions, or just give up and reinstall Windows (after confirming your disks are healthy).  This would be 1000% less painful if you can restore from a backup that existed before the corruption.

Comment: copy the folder C:\Windows\losg\CBS to the desktop, create a zip and share the zip (Cloud service like Dropbox, OneDrive)

Comment: Google says http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/windows-update-error-80070490#1TC=windows-7 as 1st hit...

Answer (score 0):

Your best shot (with the little information you provided) is to use the windows installation disk (or if you have an iso file) reinstall windows without removing personal files and applications.